# Use Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

in the following javascript code I see there's a use of the command function, but it didn't specify the name of the function. What's this all about?

```
var getReview = function(movie) {
    switch (movie) {

    case "Matrix":
        return "good trip out";
        break;
    case "Princess Bride":
        return "awesome date night movie";
        break;
    case "Welcome to America":
        return "Amjad's favorite";
        break;
    case "Remember the Titans":
        return "love the sports";
        break;
    case "Why do I look like I'm 12?":
        return "The Ryan and Zach story";
        break;
    case "Fighting Kangaroos in the wild":
        return "Token Australian movie for Leng";
        break;
    default:
        return "I don't know!";
    }
};​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [anonymous function](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/).

Quoting from the link above:

> Anonymous functions are declared using the function operator. You can
>   use the function operator to create a new function wherever it’s valid
>   to put an expression. For example you could declare a new function as
>   a parameter to a function call or to assign a property of another
>   object.

Here’s an example where a function is declared in the regular way using the function statement:

```
function eatCake() {
    alert("So delicious and moist");
}
eatCake();
```

Here’s an example where the same function is declared dynamically using the function operator:

```
var eatCakeAnon = function() {
    alert("So delicious and moist");
};
eatCakeAnon();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a function literal. It's exactly<sup>1</sup> like a function, but doesn't have a name; it's just an object, like everything else in JavaScript, with the special part being that you can call it. Here, it's immediately assigned to `getReview`, so you can call `getReview()` to call the function.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Actually, its definition won't be hoisted, but you don't need to worry about that.</sub>